# How does one debug this compilation error without line number?

Tags: android

When I rebuild the project ((after a clean), it builds fine:

[image]

However, when I want to deploy to device (run) the build actually shows a types problem - *but* there is no line number !

[image]

How can I debug this ? Where can I find the problem? Why doesn't it give a line number ?

---

### ErrorCodeEntity.java

```
import io.realm.RealmObject;
import io.realm.annotations.PrimaryKey;

public class ErrorCodeEntity extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private long code;
    private String title;
    private String message;

    public long getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(long code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

### ErrorReport.java

```
public class ErrorReport implements Serializable {

    private String type;
    private String detail;
    private int statusCode;
    private String title;
    private int code;

    public ErrorReport(final String detail) {
        this.detail = detail;
    }


    public ErrorReport(String type, String detail, int statusCode, String title) {
        this.type = type;
        this.detail = detail;
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public ErrorReport(String type, String detail, int statusCode, String title, int code) {
        this(type, detail, statusCode, title);
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public String getDetail() {
        return detail;
    }

    public int getStatusCode() {
        return statusCode;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ErrorReport{" +
                "type='" + type + '\'' +
                ", detail='" + detail + '\'' +
                ", statusCode=" + statusCode +
                ", title='" + title + '\'' +
                ", code='" + code + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public static ErrorReport getDefault() {
        ErrorReport errorReport=new ErrorReport(
                "NO_TYPE",
                WebserviceConstants.COULD_NOT_PROCESS_REQUEST,
                -1,
                "ERROR",
                0
        );
        return errorReport;
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at places in your code where you are assigning a value to an `ErrorReport` object. Somewhere you are trying to assign a `String` instead. The code provided doesn't show any such cases, so that's all I can say for now.

Comment: Open the "Android Monitor" to look for an stack trace. You are looking the Gradle console.

Comment: this problem shows up not during run-time, but during deployment. There is *nothing* shown in the Android Monitor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found it!**

it was a compile-time error where a string was being assigned to an ErrorReport variable. However, Android Studio showed the build as being successful instead of taking me to the offending code.

Only after I clicked on the Deploy button, did the build process fail - but in a way that was useless to me.

**How I found it:**
I clicked through all of the java files in the project (quite a lot!) and to my surprise, the file with the incorrect code was suddenly underlined red.

**Notes:**

1) I previously cleaned the project but Android Studio 2.3 still looked like it compiled without error.

2) I used "Invalidate caches / restart"